# Live Webcam + Shader effects

Tags: qt, shader, webcam, effects

I want to create an application which basically captures a webcam feed and applies a custom shader effect on it, for Windows. I could use GLSL, HLSL, any shader language really.

I've tried to use Qt, which has some [very nice examples with QML and Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/video-qmlvideofx.html), but unfortunately, it doesn't capture my webcam at all! And I didn't really find any solution to my problem. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

So my question is: what tools should I use to build a simple app for this quickly? languages, APIs, any tip is kindly welcome!

Comment: What is the operating system you're using?

Comment: Gah! Sorry. I should learn to read. Do you just want to do some stock effects or did you want to write your own shader? There are a ton of ways to do this. NetPBM, .NET, and even VLC video player.

Comment: No problem =) 
I would really appreciate to be able to write my own shader!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to capture the image from the WebCam and D3D or OpenGL to create a texture form the captured image. Here is an [example](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1875).

Afterwards, I would draw a full-screen quad with the texture where you can apply your shader effects.

OpenCV can be easily built with CMake or you can download [a prebuild version](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).

Comment: thank you for this suggestion! I've used OpenCV and OpenGL a lot in the past and I agree with you, it is really powerful. I just suspect that using pure OpenGL + OpenCV may not be the most productive way to do this, considering depelopment time